# Reasons why redis dont save env data

Tags: php, session, memory, redis, environment-variables

In a project I am currently working on, there is a bug where if too many users are active on the server at the same time, it happens, that ENV variables are not beeing saved in the session by redis. (It could eventually be, that it sets the var for a second, and then returns to state before, I'm not 100% sure of it)

So far, the only reason I have found for this is that Redis is running out of memory, which I have not been able to determine. At least it was not logged. Does anyone know of any other reasons why Redis may not be able to save ENV variables?